# Oracle - Associating Durations to different 15 Minute Intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, time, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a database that provides information when an employee is logged into different states but the issue is it associates the entire duration to a 15 minute interval regardless if the duration lasts longer than the 15 minute interval which causes discrepancies when creating calculations off this data.

**Sample Dataset**:

```
**ID    | Date      | Start Time            | End Time              | Secs | State    | SubState**

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:06:41.000000000 AM | 09:09:31.000000000 AM | 170  | Ready    | Ready

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:09:31.000000000 AM | 09:44:41.000000000 AM | 2110 | NotReady | Busy

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:44:41.000000000 AM | 09:51:31.000000000 AM | 410  | NotReady | ACW

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:51:31.000000000 AM | 09:54:25.000000000 AM | 174  | NotReady | Busy

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:54:25.000000000 AM | 09:55:00.000000000 AM | 35   | NotReady | ACW
```

**Desired Result**:

```
**ID    | Date      | 15 Int  | Secs  | State    | SubState**

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:00 AM | 170   | Ready    | Ready

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:00 AM | 329   | NotReady | Busy

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:15 AM | 900   | NotReady | Busy

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:30 AM | 881   | NotReady | Busy

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:30 AM | 19    | NotReady | ACW

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:45 AM | 391   | NotReady | ACW

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:45 AM | 174   | NotReady | Busy

10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:45 AM | 35    | NotReady | Busy
```

What is the easiest way to acheive this in Oracle SQL?

Comment: 1. What is your Oracle version? 2. What if the status is Ready/Ready from 09:02 to 09:05, then NotReady/Busy from 9:05 to 9:10 and then Ready/Ready again from 9:10 to 9:35? Do you need two separate rows for Ready/Ready for the "15 Int" of 09:00, or do you need to combine the two separate intervals from 09:02 to 09:05 and from 09:10 to 09:15? (Did you even consider such non-trivial possibilities?)

Comment: Hey Mate,

The version I'm using is Oracle SQL Developer V 4.1.3.20.

I need to be able to extract each individual State and Sub State for the duration of that 15 minute interval but if two state and substates occur in the same interval they can be aggregated.

Comment: Sorry - I meant database version (as in 11.2.0.3 or 12.2.0.1) - find out by running `select banner from v$version`.

Comment: DB Version is 11.2.0.4

Comment: Also - how do you model "Start Time" / "End time" straddling over midnight? Your setup where you have separate columns for "date" and "time" is very non-Oracle; the "start time" and "end time" should both be `date` data type, which in Oracle always includes both a date component and a time component. (Or `TIMESTAMP` if you need to keep track of fractions of a second; your sample data doesn't suggest that.)

Comment: I changed the timestamp in the examples, but in the query I have converted all date/time columns to timestamp 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'

Comment: I don't understand. What you showed us - is that the original data, as stored in a table on disk, or is that the result of a query you have already written? The "dataset" as you called it is not a very good model; how do you enforce the constraint that the intervals shown for each ID are not overlapping and they don't leave gaps? A more natural arrangement should only show the "start time" in each new status; the "end time" is the "start time" of the next status. And if the data is in that format, the result you want is much easier to get to.

Comment: The first table is the raw table is the original data set except for the start/end time columns. Those originally appear as 1584475499 and I use the following to convert that into a proper timestamp;

TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ (CAST (DATE '1970-01-01' + (WDE1.START_TS/86400) AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC')AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: Do you have separate columns for DATE and Time values?

Comment: In order to convert from Unix timestamp use simply `(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + WDE1.START_TS * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney'`, there is no need to convert forth and back to/from strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a simpler answer to your problem.  While I agree with others in the comments that you should really change how you store your dates, I've adhered to it for now.  The following query should suit your needs:

```sql
WITH time_intervals AS
(
  SELECT s.min_date+(15*(LEVEL-1)/1440) AS INTERVAL_START,
         s.min_date+(15*LEVEL/1440) AS INTERVAL_END
  FROM (SELECT MIN(TO_DATE(u.event_date, 'DD/MON/YY')) AS MIN_DATE,
               MAX(TO_DATE(u.event_date, 'DD/MON/YY')) AS MAX_DATE
        FROM user_data u) s
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (s.max_date-s.min_date+1)*96 --96 is the number of 15 min intervals in a day
)
SELECT u.id AS ID, 
       ti.interval_start, 
       SUM((LEAST(ti.interval_end, u.end_time) - GREATEST(ti.interval_start, u.start_time))*86400) AS SECONDS,
       u.state,
       u.substate
FROM time_intervals ti
INNER JOIN (SELECT ud.id, 
                   TO_DATE(ud.event_date||' '||ud.start_time, 'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM') AS START_TIME,
                   TO_DATE(ud.event_date||' '||ud.end_time, 'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM') AS END_TIME,
                   ud.state, ud.substate
            FROM user_data ud) u ON GREATEST(ti.interval_start, u.start_time) < LEAST(ti.interval_end, u.end_time)
GROUP BY u.id, ti.interval_start, u.state, u.substate;
```

First, we calculate out the 15 minute intervals for the days in your table.  If you want to limit your report, just change this CTE to only account for the days you want to report.  Then we join the CTE into your existing data based on a record in your table overlapping a given interval.  Each overlapping interval is multiplied by 86400 (The number of seconds in a day) to give your result.  Finally, we use the aggregate function sum to account for multiple events with the same ID, State, and Substate within the same 15-Minute Interval.

I've created a SQLFiddle to for you to examine ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38d9e/4/0)).

Comment: Thank you, based on your SQLFiddle link, it appears to be working and I am able to adjust the logic to aggregate at 5 Minute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

This resembles a problem I've seen before. The example query I made is based on taking each 15 minute time segment and analyzing all intervals that overlap it. Trying to do it the other way around gets confusing.

I am not certain, based on the comments, whether your real data might have repeated state/substate combinations per 15 minute segment, and if so, the query below might need modification to aggregate things properly.

I noticed that in the last row of your "Desired Result", you have a SubState of "Busy", whereas in the dataset, this 35 second interval says "ACW". I assumed this was just an error and my results have the latter value.

Outline of query:

- First, we create mytable2, which takes your sample data from "mytable" and converts the start and end times to Oracle dates.
- Then, we create q1, which has one row where the column m1 is at the hour before the data and the column m2 is at the hour after the data.
- Then, we create q2, which has the starting point of all the 15 minute intervals we are interested in. Using connect by...rownum is a common pattern whenever you need some sequential numbers.

Finally, the actual query is a four-way union, where each branch joins q2 and mytable2.

- Branch #1 is where the interval is completely within a 15 minute segment.
- Branch #2 is where the 15 minute segment is completely within the interval.
- Branch #3 is where the interval starts prior to and ends within the 15 minute segment.
- Branch #4 is where the interval starts within and ends after the 15 minute segment.

```
with mytable2 as (
    select ID, date_ as "Date",
    cast(to_timestamp(date_ || ' ' ||  START_TIME, 'dd/mon/yy HH:MI:SS.FF AM') as date) "Start Time",
    cast(to_timestamp(date_ || ' ' || END_TIME, 'dd/mon/yy HH:MI:SS.FF AM')as date) "End Time",
    secs,
    state,
    substate
    from mytable
), q1 as (
select trunc(min("Start Time"), 'hh') as m1, trunc(max("End Time")+1/24, 'hh') as m2
from mytable2
),
q2 as (
select m1 + (rownum-1)/24/4 as b1, m1 + rownum/24/4 as b2
from q1, dual
connect by rownum <= (m2-m1)*24*4
)
select "ID", "Date", "15 Int", "Secs", "State", "SubState" from (
select ID, "Date", "Start Time", to_char(b1, 'HH:MI AM') as "15 Int",  secs as "Secs", state as "State", substate as "SubState" from mytable2 m
join
 q2 on "Start Time" >= b1 and "End Time" <= b2
 union
 select ID, "Date",b1 as "Start Time",  to_char(b1, 'HH:MI AM') as "15 Int", 900 , state, substate from mytable2 m
join
 q2 on "Start Time" < b1 and "End Time" > b2
 union
 select ID, "Date",b1 as "Start Time",  to_char(b1, 'HH:MI AM') as "15 Int",  round(("End Time" - b1)*24*3600,0) , state, substate from mytable2 m
join
 q2 on "Start Time" < b1 and ("End Time" between b1 and  b2)
 union
 select ID, "Date","Start Time", to_char(b1, 'HH:MI AM') as "15 Int",  round((b2-"Start Time")*24*3600,0), state, substate from mytable2 m
join
 q2 on ("Start Time" between b1 and b2 )and "End Time" > b2
) q 
order by q.ID, q."Start Time"
```

```
+-------+-----------+----------+------+----------+----------+
|  ID   |   Date    |  15 Int  | Secs |  State   | SubState |
+-------+-----------+----------+------+----------+----------+
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:00 AM |  170 | Ready    | Ready    |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:00 AM |  329 | NotReady | Busy     |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:15 AM |  900 | NotReady | Busy     |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:30 AM |  881 | NotReady | Busy     |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:30 AM |   19 | NotReady | ACW      |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:45 AM |  391 | NotReady | ACW      |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:45 AM |  174 | NotReady | Busy     |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:45 AM |   35 | NotReady | ACW      |
+-------+-----------+----------+------+----------+----------+
```

I used the following table for testing:

```
create table mytable as
select '10001' ID,'18/MAR/20' DATE_, '09:06:41.000000000 AM' START_TIME,'09:09:31.000000000 AM' END_TIME,170  secs, 'Ready' State, 'Ready' substate from dual
union all select '10001' ID,'18/MAR/20' DATE_, '09:09:31.000000000 AM' START_TIME,'09:44:41.000000000 AM' END_TIME,2110 secs, 'NotReady' State, 'Busy' substate from dual
union all select '10001' ID,'18/MAR/20' DATE_, '09:44:41.000000000 AM' START_TIME,'09:51:31.000000000 AM' END_TIME,410  secs, 'NotReady' State, 'ACW' substate from dual
union all select '10001' ID,'18/MAR/20' DATE_, '09:51:31.000000000 AM' START_TIME,'09:54:25.000000000 AM' END_TIME,174  secs, 'NotReady' State, 'Busy' substate from dual
union all select '10001' ID,'18/MAR/20' DATE_, '09:54:25.000000000 AM' START_TIME,'09:55:00.000000000 AM' END_TIME,35   secs, 'NotReady' State, 'ACW' substate from dual
```

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------+
|  ID   |   DATE_   |      START_TIME       |       END_TIME        | SECS |  STATE   | SUBSTATE |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------+
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:06:41.000000000 AM | 09:09:31.000000000 AM |  170 | Ready    | Ready    |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:09:31.000000000 AM | 09:44:41.000000000 AM | 2110 | NotReady | Busy     |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:44:41.000000000 AM | 09:51:31.000000000 AM |  410 | NotReady | ACW      |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:51:31.000000000 AM | 09:54:25.000000000 AM |  174 | NotReady | Busy     |
| 10001 | 18/MAR/20 | 09:54:25.000000000 AM | 09:55:00.000000000 AM |   35 | NotReady | ACW      |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------+
```